# Conditional/ternary operator for assignments in Python?

Tags: python, c, conditional-operator, language-features

C and many other languages have a [conditional (AKA ternary)](http://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx4eb.html) operator.  This allows you to make very terse choices between two values based on the truth of a condition, which makes expressions, including assignments, very concise.

I miss this because I find that my code has lots of conditional assignments that take four lines in Python:

```py
if condition:
    var = something
else:
    var = something_else
```

Whereas in C it'd be:

```c
var = condition ? something : something_else;
```

Once or twice in a file is fine, but if you have lots of conditional assignments, the number of lines explode, and worst of all the eye is drawn to them.

I like the terseness of the conditional operator, because it keeps things I deem un-strategic from distracting me when skimming the code.

So, in Python, is there a trick you can use to get the assignment onto a single line to approximate the advantages of the conditional operator as I outlined them?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Python has such an operator:

```
variable = something if condition else something_else
```

Alternatively, although not recommended (see [karadoc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091316/python-conditional-ternary-operator-for-assignments#comment13783847_3091332)):

```
variable = (condition and something) or something_else
```

Comment: That "variable = condition and something or something_else" doesn't even work.
For example, "True and False or True" returns True, whereas "True ? False : True" would return False.

Comment: Something or Something_else works fine right? For instance if something was null you'd set it to something_else?

Comment: @karadoc right point but bad example&no explanation for the second example: **for beginners:** if "something" is considered empty/falsy => it is evaluated to `False` => so you will **NEVER get** values like `0` (int zero), `""`(empty string), `[]` empty array, `False`, and other "empty" values => 
 ***because they evaluate to `False` => `True and False` is `False`*** :) Some languages even consider `"0"` (zero as string) as empty value :)

Comment: If `something` is an expression, is it lazily evaluated?

Comment: `count+=1 if condition else count -= 1` 
is it possible

Answer (score 21):

In older Python code, you may see the trick:

```
condition and something or something_else
```

However, this has been superseded by the vastly superior `... if ... else ...` construct:

```
something if condition else something_else
```

Comment: why don't "return if not whatever" work, though?

Comment: @Will: Because "return if not whatever" is not syntactically correct Python?

Comment: @Will Probably because you don't provide an `else` part?

Comment: You can `return 1 if not cond else 2` since that returns the expression `1 if not cond else 2`. But you can't just use `return if not cond` (even with `else`) since `if...else` is an *expression*: it evaluates to a value. You want to use `if` as *control flow* which is different. But `if not cond: return` is ok.