# Python statement of short 'if-else'

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a Python version of the following `if`-`else` statement in C++ or similar statement like this:

```
  int t = 0;
  int m = t==0?100:5;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python ? (conditional/ternary) operator for assignments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091316/python-conditional-ternary-operator-for-assignments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Ternary Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
m = 100 if t == 0 else 5 # Requires Python version >= 2.5
m = (5, 100)[t == 0]     # Or [5, 7][t == 0]
```

Both of the above lines will result in the same thing.

The first line makes use of Python's version of a "*ternary operator*" available since version 2.5, though the Python documentation refers to it as `Conditional Expressions`.

The second line is a little hack to provide inline functionality in many (all of the important) ways equivalent to `?:` found in many other languages (such as [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)).

---

Documentation of [Python - 5.11. Conditional Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: I find this shorthand "m = (5, 100)[t == 0] " a little bit weird in terms of value positioning, but it works tho

Answer (score 19):

The construct you are referring to is called the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).  Python has a version of it (since version 2.5), like this:

```
x if a > b else y
```

Answer (score 8):

```
t = 0
if t == 0:
  m = 100
else:
  m = 5
```

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.

From [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Or if you really, really must (works in Python >= 2.5):

```
t = 0
m = 100 if t == 0 else 5
```

Comment: -1. The ternary operator is *far less ugly* than a long-if for simple operations like this, quite explicit, and *way* simpler. Dogma is ugly.

Answer (score 3):

There is also:

```
m = t==0 and 100 or 5
```

Since 0 is a falsy value, we could write:

```
m = t and 5 or 100
```

This is equivalent to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I find the first shorthand handy in keyword pass-in. Example below shows that it is used in tkinter grid geometry manager.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def rcExpansion(self, rows, cols, r_sticky, c_sticky):
        for r in range(rows):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=r)
            b = Button(self, text = f"Row {r}", bg=next(self.colors))
            b.grid(row=r, column= 0, sticky = N+S+E+W if r_sticky == True else None)
        for c in range(cols):
            self.columnconfigure(c, weight=c)
            b = Button(self, text = f"Column {c}", bg=next(self.colors))
            b.grid(row=rows, column = c, sticky = N+S+E+W if c_sticky == True else None)

app = Application(root=Tk())
app.rcExpansion(3, 4, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

for print statement

```
a = input()

b = input()

print(a) if a > b else print(b)
```